# Nuxt color-mode SassError: argument `$color` of `lightness($color)` must be a color

Tags: sass, nuxt.js, bulma, buefy

My Nuxt SSR project uses Bulma/Buefy and I am trying to use the [@nuxtjs/color-mode](https://color-mode.nuxtjs.org/) module with it

Here is my vars.scss file where I define the light-mode and dark-mode classes

```
// Import Bulma's core
@import '~bulma/sass/utilities/_all';

$primary-light-color: #0075f2;
$primary-dark-color: #0015f2;
html {
  &.light-mode {
    --primary-color: #{$primary-light-color};
  }
  &.dark-mode {
    --primary-color: #{$primary-dark-color};
  }
}
// Set your colors
$white: #fdfffc;
$black: #272932;
$primary: var(--primary-color);
$primary-invert: findcolorinvert($primary);
$link: #004ba8;
$link-invert: findcolorinvert($link);
$info: #00b4d8;
$info-invert: findcolorinvert($info);
$success: #4cb944;
$success-invert: findcolorinvert($success);
$warning: #ffba08;
$warning-invert: findcolorinvert($warning);
$danger: #f06543;
$danger-invert: findcolorinvert($danger);
$facebook: #3b5998;
$facebook-invert: findcolorinvert($facebook);
$twitter: #4099ff;
$twitter-invert: findcolorinvert($twitter);
$google: #dd4b39;
$google-invert: findcolorinvert($google);
$github: #333;
$github-invert: findcolorinvert($github);

// Setup $colors to use as bulma classes (e.g. 'is-twitter')
$colors: (
  'white': (
    $white,
    $black,
  ),
  'black': (
    $black,
    $white,
  ),
  'light': (
    $light,
    $light-invert,
  ),
  'dark': (
    $dark,
    $dark-invert,
  ),
  'primary': (
    $primary,
    $primary-invert,
  ),
  'info': (
    $info,
    $info-invert,
  ),
  'success': (
    $success,
    $success-invert,
  ),
  'warning': (
    $warning,
    $warning-invert,
  ),
  'danger': (
    $danger,
    $danger-invert,
  ),
  'facebook': (
    $facebook,
    $facebook-invert,
  ),
  'twitter': (
    $twitter,
    $twitter-invert,
  ),
  'google': (
    $google,
    $google-invert,
  ),
  'github': (
    $github,
    $github-invert,
  ),
);

$navbar-height: 3.5rem;
// https://bulma.io/documentation/components/pagination/#variables
// Removed to make the pagination at the bottom of any table appear without vertical scrollbar
$pagination-margin: 0;
```

It gives me the following error

```
ERROR in ./assets/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--7-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/sass-resources-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-4!./assets/app.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: argument `$color` of `lightness($color)` must be a color
        on line 58 of node_modules/bulma/sass/components/message.sass, in function `lightness`
        from line 58 of node_modules/bulma/sass/components/message.sass
        from line 10 of node_modules/bulma/sass/components/_all.sass
        from line 7 of node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass
        from line 101 of assets/app.scss
>>       $color-lightning: max((100% - lightness($color)) - 2%, 0%);

   ------------------------------------^
```

Here is my link to [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/color-mode-not-working-9siuc?file=/assets/vars.scss:0-1876) Can someone kindly tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a `var()` (`$primary: var(--primary-color);`) instead of a color (HEX, HSL, RGB, etc).

Comment: if it isnt too much to ask, how do I fix this what do I have to pass then, new to scss :(

Comment: You need to change the value of `$primary` don't use `var()` because that's not a color it's a CSS function, you MUST use RGB, HEX, HSL. If you want to use `var()` as a color you must use it separately as bulma components have functions that require colors. You can also try making a custom/component/message.scss that modifies that component of bulma.

Comment: Just interested to know if anyone ever solved this with some workable code to preview? I've been stuck on this issue for hours.

Comment: @doubleya no luck yet

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem and got the same `Error: SassError: argument '$color' of 'lightness($color)' must be a color`.

found out that according to @PirateApp this error occurs because we gave to `lightness()` method a variable "that references to another variable instead of a color" as an argument.

this means that we **can** provide a variable as an argument, **only if our variable references to a color**. So the solution I came up with, is a little trick;
When defining a variable, make it as an adjusted color, instead of referencing to another variable.
so instead of this:

```
'white': (
     $white,
      $black,
  ),
```

we can write it this way:

```
 'white': (
     adjust-hue($white,0deg),
      adjust-hue($black,0deg),
  ),
```