# SCSS use global function return as function parameter (Nuxt project)

Tags: css, sass, nuxt.js

In a Nuxt app, I've a global *_functions.scss* file included via [@nuxtjs/style-resources](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/style-resources).

*_functions.css*

```
@function colors-medium-dark() {
  @return #{var(--colors-neutral-medium-dark, #dbe3f2)};
}
```

*CTA.vue*

Inside my component, I would like to use the return value of the above function as a parameter to the `darken` function.
I've tried the following options

```
.icon {
  stroke: darken($color: colors-medium-dark(), $amount: 5%);
}

.icon {
  stroke: darken($color: call(colors-medium-dark), $amount: 5%);
}

.icon {
  stroke: darken($color: --colors-neutral-medium-dark, $amount: 5%);
}
```

However, I get this error.

*Output*

```sh
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):                                                                                                                                                                                                                     friendly-errors 13:05:42
SassError: argument `$color` of `darken($color, $amount)` must be a color
        on line 331 of components/ui/CTA.vue, in function `darken`
        from line 331 of components/ui/CTA.vue
>>       stroke: darken($color: call(colors-medium-dark), $amount: 5%);

   --------------^
```

My function is accessible because I can use it normally if I don't wrap it into `darken`. What could be causing this error?

Comment: Are you importing the ``_functions.scss`` on top?

Comment: Not explicitely but I should have access to it via https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/style-resources

Comment: @ThéoLavaux `colors-medium-dark` returning variable declaration, but whereas `darken` method expects color value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55823860/using-css-variables-in-sass-functions-node-sass

Comment: I think I'm stuck anyway, even with the bare css property

Comment: Does this one help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69226599/8816585